# Explicity trigger useeffect without changing dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below sample code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async _ => {
        let payload = { }
      post("getdata", payload)
        .then(results => {
         console.log("results: ", results);
         })
        .catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
        });
    };
   
  }, [
    dep1,
    dep2,
    dep3
  ]);
```

I don't want to create separate function and put that insdie useeffect.

How can I trigger this use effect without changing any dependencies

Thanks

Comment: Are you basically wanting to invoke `post` manually then?

Comment: Yes, not only post, there are more codes inside that., so I want to execute everything inside useeffect just like any dependencies changed

Comment: Factor it all out into an external function that can be called by *anything*, including the effect callback.

Comment: I know that way, But I want to see if anything there which may trigger  this, as I have just started learning react

Comment: No, react hooks and dependency all tie into component lifecycle.

Comment: The purpose of React useEffect hook is to call it when component mounts into DOM and also when its dependencies change, then why'd you want to use it to achieve something not intended to achieve by it?

Answer (score -1):

Refactor the `fetchData` function out from the `useEffect` hook and wrap it with a `useCallback` hook which you can call it elsewhere inside the component:

> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
  let payload = {};
  post("getdata", payload)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log("results: ", results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, [dep1, dep2, dep3]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(); // call when fetchData has changed (due to dep1/dep2/dep3 change)
}, [fetchData]);
```

As a side note, make sure the variables in the dependency list(`dep1`, `dep2`, `dep3`) are actually used inside the hook since I am not sure if the implementation of the `fetchData` function you provided is completed or not.